# Where can I find the GoogleTest XML Schema?

Tags: xml, junit, xsd, googletest, xunit

I'm trying to validate a [GoogleTest](https://code.google.com/p/googletest/) (gtest) XML output file, and for that I need the schema/XSD for the gtest format.

I've searched online, and could not find anything. A lot seems to point at the JUnit schema, but - from what I know - they are different; GoogleTest XML supports the `value_param` field in the `<testcase>` tag, whereas JUnit does not. Similarly for the `timestamp` field in the `<testsuites>` tag.

Comment: Since GoogleTest is based on xUnit, perhaps searching for xUnit XSDs would help.  Here's one: [xunit.xsd](https://github.com/gabrielfalcao/lettuce/blob/master/tests/functional/xunit.xsd)   If that's not a match, and you've spun your wheels too long looking, start with that or the JUnit XSD, adapt, and publish your work for others to use and improve.

Answer (score 0):

In your test main process ,add  `testing::GTEST_FLAG(output) = "xml:";` when you run your test,the test result XML output just in test run directory.